# How can I debug a 503 error with Django on Apache?

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, http-status-code-503, django-wsgi

I pushed an update to my site earlier today, and when I tried to connect to it, received a Gateway Time-out error (503).

This is my error log :

```
[Wed Nov 04 01:34:26 2015] [error] [client 128.79.79.108] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'elandemdaemon': /home/python/home/elandem/edem/edem/wsgi.py
[Wed Nov 04 01:38:39 2015] [error] [client 66.249.79.153] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'elandemdaemon': /home/python/home/elandem/edem/edem/wsgi.py
[Wed Nov 04 01:39:26 2015] [error] [client 128.79.79.108] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'elandemdaemon': /home/python/home/elandem/edem/edem/wsgi.py
[Wed Nov 04 01:40:18 2015] [error] [client 109.190.112.58] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'elandemdaemon': /home/python/home/elandem/edem/edem/wsgi.py
```

And here are the contents of my wsgi.py file :

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "edem.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I reverted my changes (minor things), but the issue remains. Was it just a coincidence that the issue happend right after an update ?

When I load the site with runsever 0.0.0.0:8000, it works fine.

Is there a step-by-step way to check where this issue may be occuring ?

Comment: How are you running your site in production? Certainly not with runserver, right?

Comment: What web server are you using? Can you post the configuration?

Comment: @BobbyRussell No, using Apache and WSGI. The runserver is just to check if the app works by itself :)

Comment: @EdwinLunando We're using Apache, but I don't have control over the server. The guy in charge restarted Apache, which seems to have fixed the problem, for now.